# How to log to jenkins pipeline console output using log4j

Tags: jenkins, logging, groovy, log4j

We need to get our jenkins pipeline jobs logs into Splunk. For that I am trying to add standard logging to out project(groovy) using log4j. I have run into a lot of issues while trying to do this.

My simple pipeline job jenkinsfile code:

```
stage('Initialization') {
        steps {
            script {
                try {
                    def file = findFiles(glob: '**/foo.groovy')
                    helpers = load(file[0].getPath())
                    helpers.foo()
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    println("Error during initialization: " + e.getMessage())
                    println(e.getStackTrace().toString())
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

foo.groovy

```
@Grab('log4j:log4j:1.2.17')

import org.apache.log4j.*
import groovy.util.logging.*
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory


def foo() {
  def log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("")
  def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File("${env.WORKSPACE}/log4jconfig.groovy").toURL())
  PropertyConfigurator.configure(config.toProperties())

  log.trace "foo"
  log.debug "foo"
  log.warn  "foo"
  log.info  "foo"
  log.error "foo"
}

return this
```

I couldn't use log4j by adding annotation to a class as jenkins would say "jenkins annotation grab cannot be used in the sandbox."

Initially I tried without any configuration but it didn't work so I tried it as shown [here](https://gist.github.com/neversleepz/7381062)

log4jconfig.groovy

```
log4j {
appender.stdout = "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender"
appender."stdout.layout"="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
appender.scrlog = "org.apache.log4j.FileAppender"
appender."scrlog.layout"="org.apache.log4j.TTCCLayout"
appender."scrlog.file"="script.log"

rootLogger="debug,scrlog,stdout"
```

}

But this didn't work either. I don't get any logs in console output and no script.log file is created. Is there a way I can configure log4j in groovy so I get logs on jenkins console output.

I have already considered using echo to format logs in log4j format as :

```
def log(level, msg){
 echo "${java.time.LocalDateTime.now()} level=${level} build=${BUILD_NUMBER} job=${JOB_NAME} 
  stage=${STAGE_NAME} message=${msg}"
}
def info(msg){
 log("INFO",msg)
}
```

and this works but I want to use log4j if possible.

Comment: Does it log something when you start your script standalone (not in jenkins)? Add system property (e.g. in command line: "-Dlog4j.debug=true") to see how log4j initializes itself.